# How to create table for seperate columns in select statement

Tags: sql, select, create-table

I have a big SQL statement and I will add some columns in my new table.

```
SELECT...
      CASE...
      END as A
FROM...
WHERE...
```

How can I do this for example if I have a column based on case end statement (like column A). How can I add these columns to my new table...?

Comment: What actually you want to do?

Comment: I will create a new table and insert some of the new columns from my SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

Use a select into. Example:

```
select [all the columns I want in my new table, case statements are fine]
    into [my new table name]
    from [some table]
```